# what should I do to fix this program?

Tags: c

I have a question about the following program:
It prints:

> dst->val in f1=6
>
> dst.val in main=-528993792

I want to fix this program so it will print

> dst.val in main=6

How can I do this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct my_struct myStruct;
struct my_struct
{
    int val;
};

myStruct *f2(void)
{
    myStruct *dst = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
    dst->val = 6;
    return dst;
}



void f1(myStruct *dst)
{
    dst = f2();
    printf("**dst->val in f1=%d\n", dst->val);
}


int main()
{
    myStruct dst;
    f1(&dst);
    printf("**dst.val in main=%d\n", dst.val);
}
```

Comment: It would be scary if you could change the address of an auto-allocated object. That said, it's nice that you don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: looks like a homework assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void f1(myStruct *dst){
    myStruct *p = f2();
    printf("**dst->val in f1=%d\n", p->val);
                      //dst is the address that was copied on the stack.
    dst->val = p->val;//There is no meaning If you do not change the contents.
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: @anatolyg Do you need an explanation?

Comment: No, I don't really need it (maybe others do)

Answer (score 0):

Return your structure by value; don't use pointers and dynamic allocation:

```
myStruct f2(void)
{
  myStruct dst;
  dst.val = 6;
  return dst;
}
```

Then `f1` will use the pass-by-pointer concept more conventionally:

```
void f1(myStruct *dst)
{
    *dst = f2();
    printf("**dst->val in f1=%d\n", dst->val);
}
```

(actually, I am not sure if it's called "pass-by-pointer" or "pass-by-reference"; probably the latter is correct)